# Extracting first two words from excel before colon

Tags: excel

I want to extract the first two words in the following cell C2 before the colon

John Smith: Not attending today

```
=TRIM(LEFT(C2, FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(C2, " ", "~ ",2)&"~")))
```

I tried the above formula but it gives me "John Smith:" it gives me the colon as well

How can I just get John Smith

Comment: does the second word always end in a `:`?

Comment: Yes it it will always have a colon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
=LEFT(C2,FIND(":",C2)-1)
```

As you probably know, the FIND will tell you what position the colon is at. From there, it seems like a good place to use the "LEFT" function to count X number of characters before that position (the -1 is what makes it stop at the character before the colon)

Note that this only looks for the first colon, and also that if there's no colon, you'll get a "#VALUE" error, so if that's a possibility you're concerned about, you would need to handle it.

Comment: Do you know how to get it if I want everything after the colon?

Comment: `=RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND(":",C2))`. The "RIGHT" takes characters at the end of the string. If I did RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)), I'd get the whole string, so by adding the `-FIND(":",C2)` after the `LEN(C2)`, I remove all of the text up to and including the colon.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate,

```
=REPLACE(C2, FIND(":", C2), LEN(C2), "")
' or the reverse as,
=REPLACE(C2, 1, FIND(":", C2)+1, "")
```

Comment: Do you know how to get it if I want everything after the colon?

Comment: See addendum above. However, I would use text to columns and split on the colon.